# torch.load() Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: pytorch, segmentation-fault

python:3.6.10,torch:1.2.0,cuda:9.2

when i use torch.load() , there occurs Segmentation fault (core dumped),the torch version is 1.2.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU10J.png)

```
model_xl = torch.load("./data/models_saved/xl_model.pth")
```

after i test, if i install cpu version of torch,it's no problem ,but if i install gpu version of torch,it will occurs this problms,can anybody help me?